# How to access sharedpreference value in non-Activity Java class?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to get Shared preference values in non-Activity  Url Constants class where I need to check url which will come from a previous Activity. I am using common Shared Preference Utility class where I am using Shared Preference Manager to put and get values through shared preferences; however whenever I try to access shared preference value in Url constants class, I cannot access the common shared preference utility class. How can I get the value ? Please help.
My Shared Preference class is:

```
       public class Preference {

       private static final String PREFIX = "json";

       public static void setString(String key, String value, Context context) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = 
      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
      editor.putString(key, value);
      editor.apply();

       }
      public static String getString(String key, Context context) {
      SharedPreferences preferences = 
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
       return preferences.getString(key, null);
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass context, instead doing any hacks with context

Comment: code snippets clearly show he pass context. then what the meaning of this answer?

Comment: "How to access sharedpreference value in non-Activity Java class?" and "I try to access shared preference value in Url constants class" show that context is the problem

Comment: If u can show a small example it will be much helpful for me, I am a newbie in Android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we should get this done once and access it anywhere. What I mean is we can create a single instance of Sharedpreference when starting Application class and make any calls on this object.

```
    public class AppController extends Application {

    static AppController appController;

    public static AppController getInstance(){
        return appController;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        appController = this;
    }

}
```

get it named in *manifest* first before use in *application* tag with *name* attribute.

```
 <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        ......
        ......
</application>
```

So we can initialize here our SharedPreference or get application instance like this. We can also use [Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) for this and do much more.

```
AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

OR

we can just pass context to some constructor of a non-actvitiy/fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

AS show your code you pass context that's not problem but the problem with your class name `Preference` it should be similar to java inbuilt class like `java.android.preference` and `java.util.pref`  so make sure you are pointing your project class not android java default calss. or you may try to change your util class with other